# Weird characters for date in Win 7 explorer

Tags: windows-7, time, date

As per the screenshot be.ow, what would cause the date to be displayed like that but the time be fine? This is on a work computer for my girlfriend.

I was helping her get a new printer/scanner setup and after she scanned a document to the computer I was looking for where it was saved and noticed the date in the documents folder.

All other folders on computer seem to be the same.

[image: weird dates]

Comment: Check `region and language` settings in  control panel

Comment: Looked at that and all seemed to be fine. I didn't toggle anything and change back though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer to a [similar question found on this other site](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1528676-windows-7-dates-showing-as-random-symbols-characters), the solution seems to be to manually change/toggle the date/time format. Chances are a settings file was corrupted at some point in the system and adjusting the date/time format will rewrite that config and—hopefully—clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with character sets. You can do the following steps to repair it.

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Select the Region and Language option in the Control Panel
3. Switch to Administrative in the Region and Language property dialog
4. Select "English (United States)" in "change system locale..."